# Does Vulkan parallel rendering relies on multiple queues?

Tags: vulkan

I'm a newbie of Vulkan, and not very clear on how parallel rendering works, here's some question (the "queue" mentioned below refers specifically to the graphics queue:

1. Does parallel rendering relies on a device which supports more than one queue?
2. If question 1 is a yes, what if the physical device only have one queue, but Vulkan abstracted to 4 queues (which is the real case of my macbook's gpu), will the rendering in this case really parallel?
3. If question 1 is a yes, what if there is only one queue in Vulkan's abstraction, does that mean the device defiantly can render objects in parallel.

P.S. About question 2, when I use Metal api, the number of queues are only one, but when using Vulkan api, the number is 4, I'm not sure it is right to say "the physical device only have one queue".

Answer (score 0):

0. I have the sneaking suspicion you are abusing the word "parallel". Make sure you know what it means.
1. Rendering on GPU is by nature embarrassingly parallel. Typically one queue can feed the entire GPU, and typically apps assume that is true.
2. In all likelihood they made the number of queues equal to the CPU core count. In Vulkan, submissions to a single queue always need to be externally synchronized. Having more queues allows to submit from multiple threads without synchronization.
3. If there is only one Vulkan queue, you can only submit to one queue. And any submission has to be synchronized with mutex or coming only from one thread in the first place.